# how does node mysql driver like mysqljs/mysql communicate to the mysql server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, driver

I know how to use the node mysql driver api to connect to mysql server. But I wonder how it work under the hood? Is it has some thing todo with the mysql interactive client  program? Or does the driver use some protocal like http to talk to the mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

Connections to mysql uses its own protocol, over TCP or Unix socket.

For more details, [see the source](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/tree/master/lib/protocol).